# How to detect if no selected row in grid view c#?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

How can I detect if there is no rows selected in grid view in c#, so I can show a message that tell that no rows is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectedRows` Property to get the Count of `SelectedRows`   in `DataGridView`

```
 if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count==0)
                MessageBox.Show("No Rows Selected!");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you require.

```
 if(gridView.SelectedIndex == -1) {}
```

If you need to access the row itself, you can combine the search and retrieval as follows.

```
 if(gridView.SelectedValue !=null) {}
```